# PC:"You are an American", MSF: "No Sir, I am from Kentucky", what kind of response is that?

Tags: terminology

edit: it seems this question is better ssuited for writers se, how do i move this there?

I know following types of responses:
Truthful, dishonest, sarcastic, unclear,

In the movie edge of tomorrow, there is a dialog between Private Cage (PC) and Master Sargent Farrell:

PC:"You are an American"
MSF: "No Sir, I am from Kentucky"

What kind of response is that? It doesn't seem to fit any of response types that I am aware of. ( I don't think it sarcastic as it would have been "I am from Russia or Germany or any other obviously non intuitively wrong place.")
It is not a dishonest answer as it is truthful, yet disagreeing with the meta truth of the Kentucky being in US at the same time.

Comment: You might want to consider the history of the [American Civil War?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky_in_the_American_Civil_War)

Comment: @Margana: Holy hell, never thought of that, that would make that a disgruntle response I think! I thought I am asking a stupid question, learned something totally new :) http://history.ky.gov/landmark/kentuckys-neutrality-during-the-civil-war/

Comment: Regardless if historical background, this question is still interesting - "are you A?" followed by "no I'm B", where B is a subset of A, is a pattern I've seen with places/nationalities ("I'm not European, I'm English") as well as professional specialties.

Comment: There is also the same in terms of Welsh and Scottish national identities where they may object to being called 'British.'

Comment: @Silverfish yes, exactly, one can only ponder at other possible logical/set theoretical combinations; if it wasn't against the SE rules I would have asked for such a list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about English. Answering a question by rejecting the premise of the question is available in any language.

Comment: It's either simple sarcasm or a bit of chauvinism.  Unlike places farther south, the Civil War ended a long time ago in Kentucky.  (And one must remember that this is a movie, and, what's more, a dystopian movie.  It does not have to make sense and, in fact, a bit of disorienting nonsense is probably the goal of the screenwriter at this point.)

Comment: @Robusto : using the same logic every question should be closed as they can be asked in any language. The question is, is there a name for this type of response in English, and if yes then what is it. If there is no name for this type of response in English please go ahead and close the question, indicting that English lacks the description of this type of respone or just as I did enumerate the types of responses in English and show that none of them matches this type of response.

Comment: @Arjang: That is not the same logic.

Comment: @Arjang: I don't know where you got your "four types of response" from, but if you buy into that set of categories your example could be either *sarcastic* or *unclear*. Personally, I think that although responses are normally *governed by* (and *assessed according to*) [Grice's **four** Maxims](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html), this doesn't imply there are only four "types" of response. There are many types, and any categorization system will have overlaps (and "bucket" categories such as ***whimsical/tangential***).

Comment: @Robusto : how can we tell? i am neither sure wether it is or not, i can see arguments pro and con for it. ill try something else thanks

Comment: @FumbleFingers : now that is a good point, but if i didnt ask this i would have not found out about four maxims, thanks. so far i have learned surprising things from a stupid question, thanks to people here.

Comment: @Arjang: I'm glad you got something out of it. I closevoted along with Robusto, because I don't think the "response type" is peculiar to English, nor do I think there's a standard classification system to pigeonhole it. But you might feasibly discover different if you ask a more general question along the lines of *Is there a standard set of "conversational response types"?* over at [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: according to civil war history, i think it is a disgruntled response, his response conveys his reality he does not accept being part of US, and gives an informative response that is consistent with his reality. it seems it is all matter of perspective, and the number of ways perspectives can be combined is imho unlistable. i am very happy with what i got out of this question.

Comment: @Silverfish : i forgot to factor the relative perspectives into this. In view of MSF he does not consider himself american, hence no contradiction with Kentucky being in US. B being a particular case of A depends on the reality that one chooses or is stuck with.

Comment: In a way, grammar-wise, it could probably fall under **metalinguistic negation**. The 2nd speaker is correcting the prior speaker not because what he had said was false but because what he had said didn't go far enough. (Though, that is probably only one of the possible practical interpretations.)

Comment: @Arjang - As I said earlier, very few people in Kentucky are still fighting the Civil War, unlike places farther south.  And Kentucky *did not* secede from the US during the war, so there is no reason to be "disgruntled".  There are some who are proud of Kentucky heritage, but very little of that relates to the Civil War itself, but rather to cultural heritage -- various writers and authors, agrarian traditions, etc.  And tobacco.  And liquor.